# SPI, STM32. What is the NSS mode of operation "hardware nss output signal" for?

Tags: spi, stm32f407

In this mode, should pulses be generated from the NSS pin when transmitting data?
If I set this mode, then I do not need to connect 3 volts to the NSS pin.
The NSS pin remains always low and the SPI is recognized as the Master.

Image from Cube MX and logic analyzer
[image]

**Description from Reference Manual:
NSS output enabled (SSM = 0, SSOE = 1)
This configuration is used only when the device operates in master mode. The
NSS signal is driven low when the master starts the communication and is kept
low until the SPI is disabled.**

Yes, it makes my job easier, I don't need to connect 3 volts to the NSS pin.
But I am confused by the name of the mode "hardware nss output signal".
As if in this mode, the NSS pin should give out something.
Is it so?

Comment: Are you using the SPI as master or slave, and is the NSS input or output? Why are you connecting 3V to NSS pin?

Comment: hardware nss output signal is only used with SPI Master.
I am using hardware nss output signal with Master.

>Why are you connecting 3V to NSS pin?
>If I set this mode, then I do not need to connect 3 volts to the NSS pin.

In hardware nss output signal mode, I don't connect 3 volts to NSS.
This must be done in hardware nss input signal mode.

>and is the NSS input or output?
That's the point, I don't know exactly what the hardware nss output mode is for.

Comment: Well if you are master you don't anyway need to connect 3V to NSS. Anyway, if we forget that part then I can still anwer.

Comment: We are only talking about the hardware way to control NSS "Hardware NSS INPUT Signal".
With "Hardware NSS INPUT Signal", a voltage of 3 volts must be connected to the NSS pin.
Here is a description of this mode from the Reference Manual.

NSS output disabled (SSM = 0, SSOE = 0)
This configuration allows multimaster capability for devices operating in master
mode. For devices set as slave, the NSS pin acts as a classical NSS input: the
slave is selected when NSS is low and deselected when NSS high.

Comment: If you need the NSS as input, it means your MCU is not a master but a slave so then NSS is not an output.

Comment: My MCU is definitely the Master.
The MSTR bit in register CR1 is activated when I connect 3 volts to the NSS pin.

Comment: If your MCU is master, the NSS is an output. Please do not damage your MCU by connecting 3V to NSS output. Outputs must not be shorted to supplies or ground.

Comment: >If your MCU is master, the NSS is an output. The master has two modes: "Hardware NSS OUTPUT Signal" And "Hardware NSS INPUT Signal". In the "Hardware NSS INPUT Signal" mode, a voltage must be connected to the NSS pin. And about the "Hardware NSS OUTPUT Signal" mode, I ask in this thread what this mode is for.

Answer (score 1):

Some STM32 MCUs have pretty complex SPI peripheral. Normally with simple SPI peripheral and when using the SPI as master, the hardware has no NSS output pin and user must control any one or a number of GPIO pins to select chips. That is the software NSS mode when you don't use the hardware NSS mode.

However this SPI peripheral is quite complex and it can handle the NSS pin for you, if you first configure how many bytes you want to transfer and to which direction, when using interrupts or DMA, the SPI hardware will pull NSS low, do the transfer, and when finished it will pull the NSS high.

Comment: I checked with a logic analyzer.
The image is attached above in the post.  Yellow signal, SPI-SCS.
After data transmission, NSS in "Hardware NSS OUTPUT Signal" mode always stays low.

Comment: @stm If hardware NSS output is always low, then either the IO pin is not correctly changed from GPIO to alternate mode that is SPI NSS, or the SPI peripheral is not correctly correctly configured to make the SPI transactions. You also don't show your code so it's not possible to know why the NSS is low.

Comment: I did not show the code, so as not to confuse even more.
The MASTER NSS signal level is independent of the code in the "Hardware NSS OUTPUT Signal" mode.
NSS Master and Slave are not interconnected.

Only SPI NSS Slave is controlled via GPIO.

Comment: This behavior is described in the reference manual: "The NSS signal is driven low when the master starts the communication **and is kept low until the SPI is disabled**". The STM32 does not pull NSS back high as soon as the transfer has completed.

Comment: I quoted exactly this from the Reference Manual in my post above.
Highlighted in bold.
This is exactly what I don't understand. Why do I need a low signal level on the NSS Master?
How can I use this low signal level?
This low signal level stays low all the time and never goes high.

Comment: @stm the manual also says you terminate the transaction by disabling SPI, you quoted it yourself. It goes high when you disable SPI. You need low level on NSS pin output on master because your MCU as a master controls a slave chip which needs NSS input. Look at the SPI HAL source code to see how to use the SPI peripheral - it is complex.

Comment: > It goes high when you disable SPI.<
No, NSS does not go up when SPI is disabled.
I disabled the SPE bit in the CR1 register.
NSS never goes high.
After the data transfer is completed, NSS does not go high, after SPI is disabled, NSS does not go high either.
I checked with a logic analyzer.
And nothing is written about the high level in the Reference Manual, it is only written that NSS remains at a low level during data transfer.

Comment: @stm If you want more details, please provide which exact STM32 model you have, and code how the SPI IO pins and the SPI peripheral is initialized, and how you are controlling thr registers.